# Cannot add my user control to the toolbox from DLL file

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, .net-6.0

I created a custom WinForms control. When I added reference to the control's project for any project in the same solution, the control appeared in a WinForms designer toolbox and I can use it.

But I have problem to use it as an external library.
I built it and got a DLL file. When I add reference to the DLL file for a project, the control doesn't show in the toolbox. I tried also add it by "right click toolbox => choose items...", but I have an error: "'*path to dll*' targets a platform whose toolbox items cannot be enumerated dynamically".

**Visual Studio 2022 Community .Net 6**

Comment: [We ccould not use the .NET Framework User Control in .NET Core project directly, we should migrate it to .NET Core version or recreate it in .NET Core WinForms project.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ToolBoxs-Choose-Items----cannot-choo/1639522?viewtype=all&space=8&q=Toolbox%27s+Choose+Items)

Comment: They say 
"As far as I know the Toolbox “Choose Items…” is not supported for .NET Core WinForms project currently.

And we cannot use the .NET Framework User Control in .NET Core project directly, we should migrate it to .NET Core version or recreate it in .NET Core WinForms project."

but I created the control in .Net6 so I think this is not .Net Framework User Control. I can't migrate it or recreate, can I?

Comment: As far as I try, the same error as you is reproduced. You can try to submit your problems to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the "answer" here: [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/toolboxs-choose-items-still-cannot-browse-a-winfor/1141745)

The only solution is workaround: **Putting your controls in a NuGet package and referencing that**

Comment: What if we already are? I got my dll's from the Nuget package.